# Does anyone know a competition module suitable for magento that allows you to ask a question?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to set up a competition but the modules I have looked at just give you the basic form filling fields (name, postcode, email), disclaimer..etc

However, I cant seem to find one that allows you to ask a question for customers to answer...then submit there details.

Does anyone know any good competition modules that is compatible with magento community?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a form builder. We use [Webforms](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webforms-pro-2-form-builder.html) for most of those tasks. One client of ours for example wanted a customized "Contact us" form where his customers could also answer questions such as how they founds the site, what they would improve, which products they would like to see on the site and so on.